# How to use Arrow type in FastAPI response schema?

Tags: openapi, fastapi, pydantic, arrow-python

I want to use `Arrow` type in `FastAPI` response because I am using it already in `SQLAlchemy` model (thanks to `sqlalchemy_utils`).

I prepared a small self-contained example with a minimal FastAPI app. I expect that this app return `product1` data from database.

Unfortunately the code below gives exception:

```
Exception has occurred: FastAPIError
Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <class 'arrow.arrow.Arrow'> is a valid pydantic field type
```

```py
import sqlalchemy
import uvicorn
from arrow import Arrow
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Text, func
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy_utils import ArrowType

app = FastAPI()

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///db.db')
Base = declarative_base()

class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = "product"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(Text, nullable=True)
    created_at = Column(ArrowType(timezone=True), nullable=False, server_default=func.now())

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

product1 = Product(name="ice cream")
product2 = Product(name="donut")
product3 = Product(name="apple pie")

session.add_all([product1, product2, product3])
session.commit()


class ProductResponse(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    created_at: Arrow

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True


@app.get('/', response_model=ProductResponse)
async def return_product():

    product = session.query(Product).filter(Product.id == 1).first()

    return product

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="localhost", port=8000)
```

requirements.txt:

```
sqlalchemy==1.4.23
sqlalchemy_utils==0.37.8
arrow==1.1.1
fastapi==0.68.1
uvicorn==0.15.0
```

This error is already discussed in those FastAPI issues:

1. https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1186
2. https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2382

---

One possible workaround is to add this code ([source](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2382#issuecomment-865635415)):

```py
from pydantic import BaseConfig
BaseConfig.arbitrary_types_allowed = True
```

It is enough to put it just above `@app.get('/'...`, but it can be put even before `app = FastAPI()`

The problem with this solution is that output of GET endpoint will be:

```json
// 20210826001330
// http://localhost:8000/

{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "ice cream",
  "created_at": {
    "_datetime": "2021-08-25T21:38:01+00:00"
  }
}
```

instead of desired:

```json
// 20210826001330
// http://localhost:8000/

{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "ice cream",
  "created_at": "2021-08-25T21:38:01+00:00"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to monkeypatch pydantic's `ENCODERS_BY_TYPE` so it knows how to convert Arrow object so it can be accepted by json format:

```py
from arrow import Arrow
from pydantic.json import ENCODERS_BY_TYPE
ENCODERS_BY_TYPE |= {Arrow: str}
```

Setting `BaseConfig.arbitrary_types_allowed = True` is also necessary.

Result:

```json
// 20220514022717
// http://localhost:8000/

{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "ice cream",
  "created_at": "2022-05-14T00:20:11+00:00"
}
```

Full code:

```py
import sqlalchemy
import uvicorn
from arrow import Arrow
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Text, func
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy_utils import ArrowType

from pydantic.json import ENCODERS_BY_TYPE
ENCODERS_BY_TYPE |= {Arrow: str}

from pydantic import BaseConfig
BaseConfig.arbitrary_types_allowed = True

app = FastAPI()

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///db.db')
Base = declarative_base()

class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = "product"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(Text, nullable=True)
    created_at = Column(ArrowType(timezone=True), nullable=False, server_default=func.now())

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

product1 = Product(name="ice cream")
product2 = Product(name="donut")
product3 = Product(name="apple pie")

session.add_all([product1, product2, product3])
session.commit()


class ProductResponse(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    created_at: Arrow

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True


@app.get('/', response_model=ProductResponse)
async def return_product():

    product = session.query(Product).filter(Product.id == 1).first()

    return product

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="localhost", port=8000)
```

Comment: this Monkey Patch is strong +1

Answer (score 3):

Add a custom function with the [`@validator`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/) decorator that returns the desired `_datetime` of the object:

```py
class ProductResponse(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    created_at: Arrow

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True

    @validator("created_at")
    def format_datetime(cls, value):
        return value._datetime
```

Tested on local, seems to be working:

```sh
$ curl -s localhost:8000 | jq
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "ice cream",
  "created_at": "2021-12-02T08:25:10+00:00"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've faced similar issue and answer provided by @Karol Zlot seems to be obsolete - FastAPI was throwing JSON Schema error:

```
ValueError: Value not declarable with JSON Schema, field: name='created_at' type=ArrowType required=True
```

Below code seems to work:

```
import datetime

class ArrowType(datetime):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        return v._datetime

class Domain(DomainBase):
    id: int
    created_at: ArrowType
    updated_at: ArrowType
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is CustomArrowType for validation and serializing on Pydantic v1 and v2

```py
# pydantic < 2.0
import arrow
from pydantic import BaseModel


class ArrowPydanticV1(arrow.Arrow):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.pydantic_validate

    @classmethod
    def __modify_schema__(cls, field_schema):
        field_schema.update(
            examples=["2024-02-06 13:38:18", "2024-02-06 13:38:30+00:00"],
        )

    @classmethod
    def pydantic_validate(cls, v):
        try:
            arr = arrow.get(v)
            return arr
        except Exception as e:
            raise ValueError(f"Arrow could not parse {v!r}: {e!r}")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"PydanticV1Arrow({super().__repr__()})"
```

```py
# pydantic >= 2.0
from typing import Any

import arrow

from pydantic import (
    BaseModel,
    GetCoreSchemaHandler,
    GetJsonSchemaHandler,
)
from pydantic.json_schema import JsonSchemaValue
from pydantic_core import core_schema
from typing_extensions import Annotated


class ArrowPydanticV2(arrow.Arrow):
    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(
        cls,
        _source_type: Any,
        _handler: GetCoreSchemaHandler,
    ) -> core_schema.CoreSchema:
        
        def validate_by_arrow(value) -> arrow.Arrow:
            try:
                arr = arrow.get(value)
                return arr
            except Exception as e:
                raise ValueError(f"Arrow can not parse")

        def arrow_serialization(value: Any, _, info) -> str | arrow.Arrow:
            if info.mode == "json":
                return value.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZ")
            return value   

        return core_schema.no_info_after_validator_function(
            function=validate_by_arrow,
            schema=core_schema.str_schema(),
            serialization=core_schema.wrap_serializer_function_ser_schema(arrow_serialization, info_arg=True),
        )

class Model(BaseModel):
    datetime: ArrowPydanticV2

# test
m = Model(datetime="2024-02-06 11:38:18+00:00")
print(m)
print(m.datetime)
print(m.model_dump(mode="python"))
print(m.model_dump_json())
print(m.model_dump(mode="json"))

>>>
datetime=<Arrow [2024-02-06T11:38:18+00:00]>
2024-02-06T11:38:18+00:00
{'datetime': {'datetime': <Arrow [2024-02-06T11:38:18+00:00]>}}
{"datetime":"2024-02-06 11:38:18.000000+00:00"}
{'datetime': '2024-02-06T11:38:18Z'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code example where you do not need `class Config` and can work for any type by creating your own subclass with validators:

```py
from psycopg2.extras import DateTimeTZRange as DateTimeTZRangeBase
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import TSTZRANGE
from sqlmodel import (
    Column,
    Field,
    Identity,
    SQLModel,
)

from pydantic.json import ENCODERS_BY_TYPE

ENCODERS_BY_TYPE |= {DateTimeTZRangeBase: str}


class DateTimeTZRange(DateTimeTZRangeBase):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        if isinstance(v, str):
            lower = v.split(", ")[0][1:].strip().strip()
            upper = v.split(", ")[1][:-1].strip().strip()
            bounds = v[:1] + v[-1:]
            return DateTimeTZRange(lower, upper, bounds)
        elif isinstance(v, DateTimeTZRangeBase):
            return v
        raise TypeError("Type must be string or DateTimeTZRange")

    @classmethod
    def __modify_schema__(cls, field_schema):
        field_schema.update(type="string", example="[2022,01,01, 2022,02,02)")


class EventBase(SQLModel):
    __tablename__ = "event"
    timestamp_range: DateTimeTZRange = Field(
        sa_column=Column(
            TSTZRANGE(),
            nullable=False,
        ),
    )


class Event(EventBase, table=True):
    id: int | None = Field(
        default=None,
        sa_column_args=(Identity(always=True),),
        primary_key=True,
        nullable=False,
    )
```

link to Github issue:
https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues/235#issuecomment-1162063590

Comment: Nice, but I think your solution doesn't work with Arrow type.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple aproach for Pydantic V2 with Annotated types

```py
# Optional, you can just use `float` instead
TimeStamp = Annotated[
    float,
    WithJsonSchema(
        {"type": "float", "example": arrow.now().timestamp()}, mode="serialization"
    ),
]

PydanticArrow = Annotated[
    arrow.Arrow,
    PlainSerializer(lambda x: x.timestamp(), return_type=TimeStamp, when_used="json"),
]


class SimpleSchema(BaseModel):
    id: UUID 
    create_time: PydanticArrow
```